# Update table from sub query is performing really slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am having a tough time solving a SQL problem. I have scoured the internet already and failed to find a solution.

I've provided some context below. I've only included what I think is relevant.

**Existing Tables:**

```
Group
id - has index

Admin
id - has index

Post
id - has index
group_id - has index
admin_id - has index
```

**My Problem:**

There used to be a bug in the software that was not populating the `admin_id` column when a post is created. This was okay because up until now it was assumed that every group would only have one admin.

We are now adding functionality to have multiple admins for each group, so `admin_id` needs to be populated. The bug in the software has been fixed, but we have to go back and populate the `admin_id` for each post.

**My Solution/Question:**

What am I doing wrong? Below is my query. It literally takes 45 minutes to run. I cannot find a way to fix this. I am okay with it taking 45 minutes if it needs to, but I really hate it and I am going crazy over finding an efficient way to do this with SQL.

```
UPDATE posts
SET admin_id = X.admin_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            posts.group_id,
            admins_groups.admin_id
        FROM posts
        JOIN groups ON posts.group_id = groups.id
        JOIN admins_groups ON groups.id = admins_groups.group_id
    ) AS X
WHERE posts.group_id = X.group_id;
```

**What I have tried so far.**

Besides scouring the internet and failing...

I read that indexes make writes slower, so I have removed the index on posts.admin_id and have seen a 20% performance increase, but that's still now good enough.

Comment: But the real question is: if you can get the correct `admin_Id` through a join, then why bother updating the `posts` table at all? Just join it in whenever you need it.

Comment: Wow. I feel like an idiot. Your solution worked. I didn't need groups at all and I didn't need a subquery at all. If you answer the question I will select your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you don't need the `groups` table and you should not repeat the target table of an update in the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE posts 
    SET admin_id = admins_groups.admin_id 
FROM admin_groups 
WHERE posts.group_id = admins_groups.group_id
```